# How can we compile Solidity code and receive the Bytecode back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ethereum, solidity

We're currently in the works of creating an ASP.net core application which will run on a server. But we need to compile the Solidity code and receive back ByteCode so we can use that to create and deploy a new Smart Contract to the Ethereum Network. We're using Nethereum for this.

But currently I can't find a way to compile the code on the fly on the server. I've tried using the SolcNet package but this doesn't seem to work as I get this error when using the code: `System.Exception: Library symbol failed, symbol: compileStandard` with this code:

```
// Configure the Solidity compiler
        var solcLib = new SolcLib(solSourceRoot: null, extraLibSearchDirs: new[] { "src/Tools/" });

        // Compile the Solidity code
        var sourceFiles = new Dictionary<string, string?>
        {
            { "ERC20Token.sol", smartContract.CompiledCode }
        };

        var compilationOutput = solcLib.Compile(new InputDescription(), CompileErrorHandling.ThrowOnError, sourceFiles);

        var compiledContract = compilationOutput.Contracts["ERC20Token.sol"][smartContract.ContractName ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()];
        var contractBytecode = compiledContract.Evm.Bytecode.Object;
        var contractAbi = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(compiledContract.Abi);
```

Nor does compile it with `Web3.Eth.Compile.CompileSolidity.SendRequestAsync();` as we don't receive back the ByteCode.

So I was wondering if you guys could help me out with this?